# jquery droplist refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with dropdown... I hav a drop down on a page and a button save.. When you choose an option of drop down you want.. and click save.. the value goes to DB and stored there.. when you go on this page again... the drop down must show the value you saved previous time... but i have a problem.. when i come to this page.. dropdown don't show me the correct value.. it shows me the first value.. but when i click on it the option that selected in this menu is right..

I think maybe i need to refresh it or something?

here is js->

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var defaultValue = Settings.getDefaultTimespan();


        if (defaultValue == $('#opt' + defaultValue).val()) {

            $('#opt' + defaultValue).attr('selected','selected');  
        }

        $('#saveBtn').click(function() {

            Settings.setDefaultTimespan(parseInt($('#timeSettingsDropList').val()));

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is HTML->>

```
            <div id="timespanSettings">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 15%"><p>Default timespan:</p></td>
                        <td style="width: 85%"><select name="timeDropList" id="timeSettingsDropList">
                                <option id="opt0" value="0">6 Minutes</option>
                                <option id="opt1" value="1">10 Minutes</option>
                                <option id="opt2" value="2">15 Minutes</option>
                                <option id="opt3" value="3">30 Minutes</option>
                                <option id="opt4" value="4">1 Hour</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
```

As you can see.. dropdown shows "6 Minutes" but selcted is "1 Hour"

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the question but jQM does this by defualt, doesn't it? Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/trdYP/5/ select a time, navigate to page 2 and back to home. Value should be as you selected

Comment: i need to save data in DB because there is another place where i need to change it.. it is settings page.. where you must choose the default value of timespan.. it won't work if you quit the application... and go there again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but what about using localStorage? Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/trdYP/19/

JS:

```
var ts = localStorage.getItem('timeSelected');

var tsList = $('#timeSettingsDropList');
tsList[0].selectedIndex = ts;
tsList.selectmenu("refresh");

$('#timeSettingsDropList').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('timeSelected', $(this).val());
    ts = localStorage.getItem('timeSelected');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="timespanSettings">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 15%"><p>Default timespan:</p></td>
                    <td style="width: 85%"><select name="timeDropList" id="timeSettingsDropList">
                            <option id="opt0" value="0">6 Minutes</option>
                            <option id="opt1" value="1">10 Minutes</option>
                            <option id="opt2" value="2">15 Minutes</option>
                            <option id="opt3" value="3">30 Minutes</option>
                            <option id="opt4" value="4">1 Hour</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#page2">View Page 2</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page2"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f"> 
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li> 
            <li><a href="#home">View Home Page</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK Thanks..that helped ->>> $('#timeSettingsDropList').selectmenu("refresh");

Answer (score 0):

To select the option in a dropdown list you just have to pass the value in the val method like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var defaultValue = Settings.getDefaultTimespan();

        $("#timeSettingsDropList").val(defaultValue);

        $('#saveBtn').click(function() {

            Settings.setDefaultTimespan(parseInt($('#timeSettingsDropList').val()));

        });
    });
```

Comment: ou.. i tried that.. but the result is the same..I mean that the value is changing.. but the text in dropdown don't

Comment: You might have kept your old code as well which was actually setting the selected attribute of option. Please check my edited answer I have written the complete code. Thanks

Comment: What is exactly happening can you please explain?

Comment: i saved the value for example "2" (15 Minutes)... and exit that page.. when i return.. in dropdown is shown "6 Minutes" (the first value).. but when i click on this drop down..opening full lista of values... and there is correct value..

Comment: It depends on what Settings.getDefaultTimespan() it returns. Please take a look at this method.

Comment: What do you mean by [when i click on this drop down..opening full lista of values... and there is correct value]?

Comment: The code above will set timeSettingsDropList with whatever value Settings.getDefaultTimeSpan() returns on page load. What else do you expect?

Comment: wait please.. i'll made a image

Comment: Are you sure the value of 1 hour is not as 6 minutes in the list?

Comment: yeah..i'm sure.. the values are from 0 to 4